How to unblock dnsbl on senderscore.org
I just sent a message to a small group of friends and it appears to have been rejected by comcast with the following:
<xxx@comcast.net>
    (reason: 554 resimta-c2p-560312.sys.comcast.net resimta-c2p-560312.sys.comcast.net a.b.c.d found on one or more DNSBLs, see https://postmaster.comcast.net/smtp-error-codes.php#BL000100)

If I check
https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php
the ip it's complaining about
a.b.c.d
comes up clean.
The
https://postmaster.comcast.net/smtp-error-codes.php#BL000100
redirects to
https://spa.xfinity.com/postmaster?faq=comcast-mail-errors#BL000100
Which references
https://senderscore.org/assess/blocklist-lookup/#
The senderscore site seems to be catering to email marketers, and it appears comcast thinks I'm a marketeer/spammer.
Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?  Is there a way to find which dnsbl it thinks the ip is listed on?
The email itself might have been categorized as spam, as it contained information about a startup I'm involved with, and I suspect the subject line may have done the same.  However, clean email from a different from addr (same domain/ip) is also being blocked.

You are asking about some, by nature, public address. What is the point of putting a.b.c.d in your post, I cannot look that up. Also, just check your sending IP with spamhaus. They usually know (even if its not their list that the recipient uses).

spamhaus says it's clean also.  The ip is 66.109.141.57
